# Jprofiler and G1 GC

Tags: jprofiler

I was trying to profile my spark application (that uses the G1 GC) using jprofiler. I came across their website where they mention that jprofiler remote profiling works reliably only with the standard garbage collector:

http://resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/index.html
(Under section Probe Settings/Starting Remote Sessions)

"Please note that the profiling interface JVMTI only runs reliably with the standard garbage collector. If you have VM parameters on your command line that change the garbage collector type such as

```
-Xincgc
-XX:+UseParallelGC
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:+UseParNewGC
```

please make sure to remove them. It might be a good idea to remove all -XX options if you have problems with profiling."

Is this true for the latest version of jprofiler as well (9.0) ? Does this affect cpu profiling as well  ?

I am able to do a memory profiling with visualVM, just wondering why this limitation (if at all) with jprofiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a limitation, it's just advice. Some of the alternative GCs are not well tested with the JVMTI (the profiling interface of the JVM). G1 GC will become the standard GC, so there the situation is different.